# Typescript Error: Type 'A | B | C' is not assignable to type 'C'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I left here a link to the CodeSandbox where i have replicated the error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-snowflake-po37o2
Thanks in advance!

Update:
I add here a screenshot
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0GwV.png)

Comment: Errm.. where is that error in the CodeSandbox?  I see other errors but not "Type 'A | B | C' is not assignable to type 'C'."

Comment: @RichN Please, see the screenshot in the Update. Thnx!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem arises because your three button interfaces aren't similar enough, meaning your field - field in different button interfaces differ.

To fix this you can update your intercaes like this

```
interface IButtonColumn extends IColumnBase {
  type: ColumnTypes.BUTTON;
  fields: Array<IField & fieldsSecondType>;
}

interface IIconButtonColumn extends IColumnBase {
  type: ColumnTypes.ICON_BUTTON;
  fields: Array<IField & fieldsSecondType>;
}

interface IRadioButtonColumn extends IColumnBase {
  type: ColumnTypes.RADIO_BUTTON;
  fields: Array<IField & fieldsSecondType>;
}

interface fieldsSecondType {
  label?: string;
  icon?: JSX.Element;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've confused the TypeScript compiler.  It can't tell whether the Comp2Props object you're constructing to pass to Comp2 is valid.  In particular it can't tell whether the constraints between the type and fields properties have been met even though they have.

The usual approach when the compiler is confused like this is to give it a little help, often with a cast.  The code below works, although it's a little ugly.  It constructs the appropriate object, casts it to the right type, and then uses the spread operator, which lets you pass an object with props as properties to a component in React.

Comp1.tsx

```
import { ColumnTypes, Comp1Props, Comp2Props } from "./types";
import { Comp2 } from "./Comp2";

export const Comp1 = ({ col }: Comp1Props): JSX.Element => {
    const rowId = "ROWID";
    const isSelected = true;
    if (
        col.type === ColumnTypes.BUTTON ||
        col.type === ColumnTypes.ICON_BUTTON ||
        col.type === ColumnTypes.RADIO_BUTTON
    ) {
        return (
            <>
                <br />
                <Comp2 {...
                    {
                        id: col.id,
                        type: col.type,
                        fields: col.fields,
                        rowId: rowId,
                        isSelected: isSelected
                    } as Comp2Props
                } />
                <br />
            </>
        );
    }
    return (
        <>
            <br /> - No Button:
            {col.name}
            <br />
        </>
    );
};
```